# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Player')"

Tags: mysql, node.js, next.js, backend, mysql2

I am trying to POST data to my MySQL database from my Next.js project but i am encountering an issue.

This is my frontend

```
import React from 'react'
import { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';

const formReducer = (state,event)=>{
    return{
        ...state,
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    }
}

const Addplayer = () => {

    const[formData, setformData] = useReducer(formReducer,{}) 
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData)
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        };
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/addplayer', options);
            const json = await res.json();
            console.log(json);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

This is my backend

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise"
import App from "next/app"
let club = 10;
let player_id = 302;
export default async function handler(req, res) {

    
    const dbconnection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost" ,
        database: "football",
        //port: 8889,
        user: "root",
        password: "",
    })
    try{
        const FormData = req.body.formData;
        console.log(FormData);
        await dbconnection.query("INSERT INTO player (player_id, player_name, Country, Position, Age, Club, club_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" , [player_id, FormData.Player, FormData.Country, FormData.Position, FormData.Age, FormData.Club, club])
        res.status(200).json({ players: FormData });
    } catch ( error ) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
    }
}
```

When I add a new entry, I am getting the correct formData in my frontend but it is undefined in the backend.

This msg is displayed in my http://localhost:3000/api/addplayer

`{"error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Player')"}`

And I am getting this error in my Frontend console

`addplayer.js?543d:24POST http://localhost:3000/api/addplayer 404 (Not Found)`

How do I solve this?

forgive me If I have done any simple mistake as this is my first time Using nextjs with MySQL.

Thank you

I want to add a new player to the database.

Comment: Do you use express.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
const FormData = req.body;
```

instead of

```
const FormData = req.body.formData;
```